# How do I Read file line by line and ignore comments?

Tags: c++, file, sorting, readfile, getline

I have a text file consists of

```
//range of X
X=1-5

//range of Y
Y=1-5
```

How do i read the file so that it ignore comments and empty lines and gets the output of:

X=1-5

Y=1-5

```
int main(){

    string fileName,X;
    cout << "Please enter filename: " ;
    cin >> fileName;


    ifstream infile;    
    infile.open(fileName);  

        if (!infile){       
            cerr << "Error opening : " << fileName << ", file does not exist" << endl;
            return -1;      
        }


    while(getline(infile, X)){
        cout << X;
    }

    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are there assumptions you are using? i.e., single line comments only? Comments always at beginning on line? I see you started to put in code to read a file, but you should also put in code of your attempt to do this part of the problem too.

Comment: What if it is `X=1-5 // Here is a comment`?

Comment: Yup i only have single line comments starting with //

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, comments are always on separate lines using operator "//".

```
if(X.size() == 0 || (X.size() >= 2 && X[0] == '/' && X[1] == '/')){
     continue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
while(getline(infile, X)){
    cout << X;
}
```

By

```cpp
while(getline(infile, X)){
    if((X.size() >=2 && X.substr(0,2) != "//") && X.find_first_not_of(' ') == X.npos) cout << X;
}
```

An Edit to store the two lines:

Replace your `while` by the following

```
vector<string> twoStrings;
while(getline(infile, X)){
if((X.size() >=2 && X.substr(0,2) != "//") && X.find_first_not_of(' ') == X.npos)
    {
        cout << X;
        twoStrings.push_back(X);
    }
}
//Now the first line is stored in twoStrings[0] and the second line is stored in twoStrings[1]
```

Comment: What if the line is `/apples` or `[spaces] X=5` … You code wouldn't work.

Comment: There was some small errors which I fixed. I don't know if it will actually work, but it seems alright now.

Comment: @anonymous your `if` is still buggy, all of your conditions are wrong. It should be more like this instead: `if ((X.substr(0,2) != "//") && (X.find_first_not_of(' ') != X.npos))`

Comment: i cout and got x=1-5 y=1-5, but how do i store the 2 strings in 2 different variables?